# Can I use 8 bits out of 16 bits as signed bits in verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

Generally Verilog takes the first bit of any bit pattern as signed bit. I know that `-4` can be represented in signed representation as `1100` (four bit representation).

If I have a `16 bit` hexadecimal data `FF04` can I convert it into `-04` leaving `FF` as sign bits?

Comment: Your question is unclear specific the part about "convert to decimal". Verilog itself does not support a 'decimal' format. Do you mean BCD or do you mean when you use $display/$write? Note that the signed range of 8 bits is limited to -128..127!

Comment: thank you, i simply want to say if i have a data FF04 how can i convert it into -04

Comment: Your question is not very clear. First, are you clear on the difference between two's-complement and sign-magnitude representations for signed numbers? Can you explain **in general** what you want to do rather than with one or two examples?

Comment: @David what would become of FE04?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Verilog treats bit patterns as unsigned. `16'hFF04` is an unsigned hex pattern with the decimal value 65284. You can write it as `16'shFF04` which is -252 in decimal. All signals/wires/variables in Verilog are unsigned with the exception of `integer`.

The *signedness* of a value or variable only matters when extending it to a larger width, or when used in a relational operator. Any time you truncate it, it is treated as unsigned. And it's up to you in determining what throwing away those upper bits means. Generally, if you truncate signed values and the MSB changes from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1, you have an overflow condition.

Answer (score 1):

To the question in the title:

Just truncate it.

As long as your number is within range of the smaller bus (i.e. 0 to 255 or -128 to 127 for 8bit), then you don't have to do anything special.

If you want the truncated value to be treated as signed, just assign it to a variable declared as such:

```
wire signed [7:0] small = big[7:0].
```

---

As to the body of your question, there are some things that don't make sense. For example 16'hFF04 does not represent -4, it represents -252 in Verilog signed.

It looks to be that you are talking about not twos complement, but rather sign-magnitude. If this is the case, you will have to add logic to do the conversion.

For example:

```
assign twos = simag[8] ? -{1'b0, simag[6:0]} : {1'b0, simag[6:0]};
```

That would take you FF04 and convert it to -8'd4, assuming that the magnitude is in range.